# How to draw a *simple* line segment with d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

In the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line) for d3.js I cannot find a straightforward way to draw a *simple* line segment between two points.  The only way I can find there to do this is one that requires creating callbacks for x and y, etc., etc.  I.e. a *major* production just to draw a simple line segment.

Is there something simpler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest is:

```
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .attr({
    d: "M0,0L200,200"
    stroke: '#000'
  });
```

This is not too bad:

```
var simpleLine = d3.svg.line()
d3.select('svg')
  .append('path')
  .attr({
    d: simpleLine([[0,0],[200,200]]),
    stroke: '#000'
  });
```

Still....

I don't know if this is more simple, but it is maybe more direct:

```
d3.select('svg')
  .append('line')
  .attr({
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 200,
    y2: 200,
    stroke: '#000'
  })
```

(All three examples draw a line from 0,0 to 200,200)

Comment: Thanks, though, come to think of it, I think I'll just break out the ol' `.attr(d:"M0,0L200,200")`, and let it rip.