# Trouble drawing lines from data in d3.js + data manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

(Check out the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55HEV/7/)** for the full source)

I'm having issues drawing lines from a map{node:node} using d3.js.

The offending block of code is the following:

```
svg.append("path")
    .data(connections)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { 
        console.log(d.source.age);
        return d[0].age * 8 + 5; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d[0].height; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d[1].age * 8 + 5; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d[1].height; })
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

I'm trying to connect nodes to their children via lines. The json data is shown in the Fiddle.

I clearly have some issue with the ordering of the .functions. Having little js experience doesn't help.

Furthermore, I'm having an issue with pushing data into my objects in this block:

```
for(var source in people){
    source.height = Math.random() * 400 + 5;
    source.width = source.age * 8 + 5;
    for(var i in source.children){
        connections.push({source : people[i]});
    }
}
```

source.width and source.height are undefined.

Any reason why settings the fields here doesn't work, but the following does:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(people)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.age * 8 + 5;
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d) {
       d.height = Math.random() * 400 + 5; //THIS!!!
       return d.height;
   })
   .attr("r", 5);
```

I looked through

[How to draw a *simple* line segment with d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236149/how-to-draw-a-simple-line-segment-with-d3-js)

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

but the conversion to my particular json data and usage isn't straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually closer than you think -- the almost working code is there, just commented out! The `var i in foo` syntax you're using doesn't work like that in Javascript. To iterate over an array, you have to use the old-fashioned loop or `.forEach()`. The working code looks like this.

```
var connections = [];
for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var numChildren = people[i].children.length;
  var children = people[i].children;
  for(var j = 0; j < numChildren; j++) {
    connections.push({
        source : people[i],
        target : people[children[j]]
    });
  }
}
```

Apart from fixing the variable names, the only thing I have changed is to use `children[j]` as an index into `people` rather than the value itself. In the rest of the code there's only a typo: instead of `svg.append("path").data(connections)`, you need `svg.selectAll("line").data(connections)`, in line with the usual D3 data binding pattern.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/55HEV/10/).

Comment: Thank you, Lars! That's really helpful and enlightening.