# A scatterplot with links between points using d3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a visualization using d3 which is basically a scatter plot with links between the points. (I have attached a .gif of the existing java based visualization)

The points can be added by double clicking other points. On hovering over a point, I wish to have links drawn between the point and all its partners on screen.

I have the part where on double clicking a node, its partners are added. What I need help with is drawing the links (primarily I am not able to understand how can I get the x1,y1,x2,y2 values required to draw the links).

This is what my DOM looks like:

[image]

[image: scatternet]

I have seen a lot of examples online but somehow not able to figure the solution - if anyone could link me to a similar visualization or share a fiddle/ give some pointers on how this can be achieved I would be really grateful.

Comment: the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are just the starting and end points of your lines, so to connect two circles you need to feed the line function the centers (in x,y coordinates) of the points you want to connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the simple stuff: here are [2 mechanisms for drawing the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236149/how-to-draw-a-simple-line-segment-with-d3-js/19236813#19236813).

Next, in terms of the data representation of the lines, [check out](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) how links are typically drawn when working with the force directed layout.

Important: Do **not** get distracted by the existence of the force layout in this example and by the fact that the force layout works with these links (which are passed into it by calling `force.links(links)`). That aspect of the example probably doesn't have an equivalent in what you're trying to achieve.

However, **do** notice how the `links` array is constructed —— with each element of the array being an object with pointers to `source` and `target` datums. In your case, you'll want to work with a similar `links` array, where `source` is the node under the mouse and `target` is a node that's connected to it. So you'll end up with an array of links who all have the same `source` datum but unique `target` datums.

You can then bind the `links` array (via the usual `.data()` method) to a d3 selection of `line` or `path` elements. Once you bind, you can use the usual enter, update, exit pattern to append, update and remove (on mouse out) the drawn lines.

Given a `source` and `target` datums, you can calculate the x and y of the endpoints in the same way you currently calculate the translation of each `<g>` element, presumably using a d3 scale.

Comment: Thank @meetamit .. . I saw the answer now . .but I did use the logic of the node-links as in the case of a FDN (i.e. the source and target indexes) .. was able to get it running. :)

Comment: Just to clarify: You don't need the force direction; just a well constructed line set of graphs.